# Countdown with hours and minutes - compute the difference

Tags: php, date

I have two dates:

```
$today = '2012-12-01 10:40:00';
$check = '2012-12-03 12:00:00';
```

How can I show countdown for this dates?
Should show me:

Count: **49** hours and **20** minutes. I can check only hours or only minutes with function mktime, but how can i compare this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, is it limited to hours/minutes, or would there be cases where if the countdown exceeds a certain amount, it goes to days/hours/minutes, weeks/days/hours, etc.?

Answer (score 4):

try using [`DateTime::diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2012-12-01 10:40:00');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2012-12-03 12:00:00');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%1 day %h hours %i minutes');
?>
```

Comment: Thats because it starts at the 0th hour.

Comment: Yes but OP had a '49 hours' example.

Comment: this is good, but this show also days - i would like only hours and minutes

Answer (score 2):

You can change these dates to a unix timestamp with `strtotime`.
Then you can calculate the difference between them in seconds.

60 seconds in a minute, 60 minutes in an hour.

Comment: This is very basic programming, I would suggest simply giving it a shot :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the clock to keep ticking as the user stays on the page, you don't really want to do that using PHP (unless you want to dispatch AJAX calls to the server every second to update the clock, which would suck). Do it client-side, using javascript.

Here are 25 pretty scripts that do that using jQuery: http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/11/jquery-countdown-scripts.html